# Received an error when trying to check for storyboard in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

When trying to test the bounds to correspond with storyboards, I received an error "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". I looked up a few ways to fix it, like Product>clean and running it as a test program, but neither worked. This happened after I implemented the test I used below. Is there any other way to fix this?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

    if(result.width == 960){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone4.xib" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    }
}
return YES;
```

Edit: i commented this part out and still received the error. It leads me to believe that it may come from the new xib I created for the 4, but i'm not completely sure.

Edit 2: i've also checked to make sure everything is added in build phases > compile sources and the xib is in copy bundle resources.

Comment: Since this is a linker error - there should be a message on which symbol was not resolved -- show that message. [Asside: I didn't think a `xib` file could be used in place of a  `storyboard`.]

Comment: Just created a storyboard instead of an xib, still didn't work. 

I'm not seeing where the message is exactly, the only thing i can relatively find is 
ld: 11 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) and on the left it's a Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Comment: Somehow there are 11 symbols defined more than once. What makes you think the issue is within this window of code?